# jQuery: Is it possible to attach event handlers from within another handler?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Context: I have a click event handler that is activated when a particular tab is clicked. Now within that click event handler, I am trying to add another event handler for one of the dynamically generated elements within that tab.

Question:  Is it actually possible to attach event handlers from within another handler? For instance, a click handler from another click handler?

Here is the code that is giving me problems... I can't seem to be able to successfully attach click handlers to the dynamically generated input.

```
    var main = function () {
    'use strict';


    var todos = [
        ...
    ];


    $('.tabs a span').toArray().forEach(function (element) {

        var $element = $(element),
            $content,
            $li,
            $button,
            add_note,
            input_value;


        $element.on('click', function () {

            ...

            $('main .content').empty();


            // 1st tab
            if ($element.parent().is(':nth-child(1)')) {

                ...

            // 2nd tab
            } else if ($element.parent().is(':nth-child(2)')) {

               ...

            // 3rd tab
            } else if ($element.parent().is(':nth-child(3)')) {

                // add DOM elements
                $button = $('<button>').text('+');
                $content = $('<input>').add($button);


                add_note = function () {

                    input_value = $('main .content input').val();

                    if (input_value !== '') {
                        todos.push(input_value);
                        $('main .content input').val('');
                    }
                };

                //
                //  attach keypress and click handlers
                //
                $('main .content input').on('keypress', function (event) {

                    // check for 'enter' keypress
                    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                        add_note();
                    }             
                });

                $('main .content button').on('click', function (event) {
                    add_note();
                });
            }


            $('main .content').append($content);
            return false;
        });
    });

    ...
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are trying to use and isn't working?

Comment: I can if you really insist, but I am asking a general question... is it possible?

Comment: .... but it is usually a bad idea to do that.

Comment: Just be careful that if the user clicks your tab several times you don't bind extra handlers to the other elements.

Comment: _is is possible_ absolutely but what did you have? there is a better way like event delegation syntax.

Comment: @nnnnnn The elements are dynamically generated, and cleared after another tab is clicked. So do I really have to worry about the handlers being attached multiple times?

Comment: Well I said "be careful", not "never do this". If you're confident it won't be a problem then go ahead. As for why your code doesn't work, you're trying to bind the event handlers to elements not yet added: your on() calls come before your append(), so $('main .content input') won't match any elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can takeout your event bindings on dynamic elements and convert them using delegated event:

```
$('main').on('keypress', '.content input', function (event) {
    // check for 'enter' keypress
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        add_note();
    }             
}).on('click', '.content button', function (event) {
    add_note();
});
```

Comment: Okay, that's one way... but I am wondering why my own code doesn't work since I heard that it is possible to add handlers from within handlers.

Comment: Because at that point of time the element you are targeting it is not in the dom. you are appending it later but you are trying to bind before.

Comment: Aaaaah! The penny just dropped. Okay, so is the way you suggested the only way to do this in jQuery? Or is there another method. Also, would you kindly provide a reference that I can look up and study to understand your answer more. Thanks.

Comment: Grateful - this isn't the only way, but usually it is the best way. The way you were doing it would also work if you did it in the right order, that is, move the append() to before the on() calls.

Comment: Aaaah, again! Okay, I get the concept. Thanks to all the help.

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else pointed out, the posted code doesn't work because the dynamically generated elements do not exit in the dom yet. However, instead of using delegated event handlers, as some have highlighted above. It is much simpler to attach handlers directly to the jQuery objects (instead of the selectors).

So the following would work:-

```
// add DOM elements
$input = $('<input>');
$button = $('<button>').text('+');
$content = $input.add($button);

//  $('main .content input').on('keypress', function (event) {
$input.on('keypress', function (event) {
    ...
});

// $('main .content button').on('click', function (event) {
$button.on('keypress', function (event) {
    ...
});
```